# Is there any way to start a process in background in Windows leaving the service option apart

Tags: windows, service, process

I know a way to set up a program that can be started whenever window is rebooted by creating an entry of that process in the registry :

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

But can anybody please tell is there any way to make that process to run in background. I am  not considering services due to credentials issues I encountered.

Comment: You'll first need to define what exactly it is you mean by "run in the background".  Also, note that using the `Run` registry key will only work when a user logs in, not as soon as the machine starts up.

Comment: @HarryJohnston "run in the background" means no console window should open for that process when I login.

Comment: @javabinder In that case your question has been answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no formal concept of a background process in Windows. I guess what you mean is that you don't want the process to show a GUI. You can achieve that by:

- Making the process target the GUI subsystem rather than the console subsystem. A process that targets the console subsystem is automatically given a console window when it is started.
- Not creating a visible window.

If you wish the process to run with a lower priority then you can do that by calling `SetPriorityClass` but I'd be surprised if you needed to do that.